# Matlab Midpoint in 2D domain

Tags: matlab

Given a domain (2D grid) and two lines:

```
D = [-0.99 0.99;-0.99 0.99]; %domain
x = 0.0676 ;
y = 0.7630];
```

with the lines given as a vector:

```
pt = [0.0676 0.7630]
```

what is the most efficient way for me to find the four midpoints in Matlab?

Thank You

Comment: Four midpoints of what? Where are the two lines? I assume your domain is a square grid ranging from -0.99 to 0.99.

Comment: My domain is a square grid [-0.99,0.99]*[-0.99,0.99]. And the two lines break the domain into 4 subdomains. I'm looking for a way to find the midpoint to these subdomains.

Comment: I don't understand how `[0.0676 0.7630]` can give you 2 lines. Maybe a diagram could help, or a more thorough explanation. What code have you written so far and why doesn't it work as you intended?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question right, you're trying to achieve this.

[image: Matlab Plot of Code]

This code does it, you can certainly improve the performance by making better use of vector and matrix operations, but if it's only for a problem this simple the optimization isn't worth it.

```
dlim_x = [-0.99 0.99];
dlim_y = [-0.99 0.99];
x = 0.0676;
y = 0.7630;

domain_vec_x = [dlim_x(1) dlim_x(1) dlim_x(2) dlim_x(2) dlim_x(1)];
domain_vec_y = [dlim_y(1) dlim_y(2) dlim_y(2) dlim_y(1) dlim_y(1)];
line(domain_vec_x, domain_vec_y);
line([x x], dlim_y, 'linestyle', ':');
line(dlim_x, [y y], 'linestyle', ':');
xlim([1.1*dlim_x]);
ylim([1.1*dlim_y]);
hold on;

x1 = mean([dlim_x(1), x]);
x2 = mean([x, dlim_x(2)]);
y1 = mean([dlim_y(1), y]);
y2 = mean([y, dlim_y(2)]);

plot(x1,y1,'^')
plot(x2,y1,'^')
plot(x1,y2,'^')
plot(x2,y2,'^')
```